# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: title, description, cloth_type, pic Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, mass-assignment

When doing a POST to /cloth/create I get a WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: title, description, cloth_type, pic

cloth.rb

```
class Cloth   
  include Mongoid::Document   
  include Mongoid::Timestamps 
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes   attr_accessible :pics

  field :title   
  field :description   
  field :cloth_type   
  belongs_to :seller   
  has_many :pics

  attr_accessible :pic_attributes   
  accepts_nested_attributes_for:pics
end
```

pic.rb

```
class Pic   
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip  

  has_mongoid_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
  :storage => :cloud_files,
  :cloudfiles_credentials =>  "#{Rails.root}/config/rackspace.yml",
  :path => ":attachment/:id/:timestamp_:style.:extension"

  belongs_to :cloth
  attr_accessible :cloth_attributes

  def create        
    @cloth = Cloth.create!(params[:cloth])  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

However, I will elucidate.

By setting `attr_accessible :pic_attributes`, you are setting a white list for what attributes can be set via mass assignment. In other words, you are saying that **ONLY** the attributes you've listed can be set by doing things like `cloth = Cloth.new(params[:cloth])`. Any other attribute you are saying should be set by using their accessors, such as `cloth.title = params[:title]`.

If you need the `attr_accessible`, then add the other attributes to your list.

```
attr_accessible :pic_attributes, :title, :description, etc ...
```